# Coordinate Transformation rule of QFT field Vs. Differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, field-theory, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

I am taking my first QFT course and this has bugged me for an entire semester. Also while browsing, it looks to me that really no one in this website or any textbooks have given consistent answers.

PLEASE POINT OUT ANY MISTAKES IN THE ARGUMENT before ANSWERING BOLDED QUESTIONS.

**Question 1**: Given a $R^n$ valued function on space-time, is the transformation rule prior decided from pure differential geometry? Being said, I mean really given $f(x)$ do we know instantly what is $f’(x’),G:x\to x’=G(x)$ without any physical assumption?

Another way to ask is that We do know the transformation rule for tensor field of arbitrary type $(r,s)$ from differential geometry, (**Question 1.1**: ) so can we simply regard fields as tensor fields? For example scalar field should be $(0,0)$ type tensor field. If so, by specifying tensor type we automatically get the transformation rule. And it follows the answer to question 1 YES.

MY thinking: Let’s first give the general transformation rule according to change of coordinates in QFT: $$\phi^a(x) \stackrel{\Lambda}{\longrightarrow} \phi^{a \prime}\left(x^{\prime}\right)=S_b^a(\Lambda) \phi^b\left(\Lambda^{-1} x\right).$$ Now, for scalar field this seems to be consistent with DG transformation law, so Question 1.1 may be a YES. HOWEVER, by heart I know this is not true since the above transformation law comes really from representation of Poincare group, this is of course a additional piece of information that not prior given for an arbitrary $R^n$ valued function on space-time.  DG certainly knows nothing about representations and this is of course something we need to specify manually. What’s the problem? Shouldn’t coordinate transformation be consistent with DG?

**Question 2**: I suppose when we say “$\phi(x)$ is a scalar field”, we really mean “$\phi(x)$ transform as $\phi’(x’)=\phi(x)$”, so this is the definition of scalar field, which does not hold for an arbitrary R-valued function. This explains why a scalar function transforms differently from $R$-valued components of vector field. My question is, why transformation of vector field is not simply transforming each component separately but mixing components? It seems to me, it’s also logical to do the previous transformation.

Am I talking essentially two different things?

Comment: Please clarify what is $\phi^a(x)$? A spinor, a scalar, or a vector?

Comment: @MadMax Hi, I suppose here $\phi^a(x)$ are just a set of fields indexed by $a$, it can be a spinor, scalar, or a vector.